# windows command line find file, untar

Tags: windows-7, command-line, pipe

I want to untar a file I just downloaded in windows 7. I am in the directory, but there are too many files and the name is too long to simply type out. How would I do this in the command line? If this were linux I would use something like `ls | grep "name_approx" | tar -xvf "DEST_DIR"`. In other words, this would list all files int he directory, pipe that to grep where I would find the file name with the right "name", and pipe that lone result to the tar command, where it would unpack it and place all the files in "DEST_DIR" directory.

What's the best way to do this in windows?

Comment: I would install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Now you can extract from explorer. Select the tar file > Right click > 7-zip > Choose one of the extract options.

Comment: 7z also support command line.  You can run it like C:\>7z e -o<output dir> name_approx.zip